apache2 error.log file size
Today the sky fell down and my whole world plummeted into darkness after displaying error:
fatal error: error closing /tmp/cc8d7Oap.s: No space left on device

After reading this thread, I ran df -h -T to find my root drive 32GB was indeed 100% full. I moved my user directory /home/jay to a different drive, created a symlink back to it and bingo i was back in action with 6GB of spear space and c++ would compile again.
After no more than few hours later the root drive was full again and the fatal error: error closing /tmp/cc8d7Oap.s: No space left on device returns to haunt me again.
This time I started looking at file sizes wondering how on earth I had used 6GB of space in no more than few hours and I narrowed the problem down to a log file at /var/log/apache2/error.log that was 16GB in size, yes GB.
Stupidly not rely thinking I had no disk space, I opened the very large text file, and the computer froze for a while before dying completely.
I powered it back up to be presented with a login screen (not normally displayed, it just logs in as user/Jay by default) but couldn't get past the login screen as it says my password is incorrect even though i know it is not.
At this point I do not actually know if this login failure is due to the lack of disk space, or the fact that I changed /home/Jay to be a symlink prier to it crashing
I put the physical drive in another computer, removed the 16GB log file, reinstalled the drive back in my computer and hit the power button, bingo, I am back in action again.
This time I checked the log file /var/log/apache2/error.log and as expected it is empty. I opened Firefox, hit restore last pages, then re check the error log (within no more than like 10 seconds).
The culprit, 88247 lines (yes 88 thousand) that read:
[Mon Nov 11 00:28:30.277591 2024] [php:warn] [pid 1670:tid 1670] [client 192.168.1.1:42860] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $name in /S1/D1/web/???.co.uk/iot/index.php on line 376

I can see the fix to my immediate problem being go to the index.php file and correct line 376.
But my question really is:
Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening in the first place (like limit the log size or something) since a stupid user with access to modify a web page (yes that would be me) can single-handedly crash out the entire server without even trying to be malicious.

not that i really care but thanks for the silent down vote, i just wish you could have had the decency to say something, i would rather be punched in the face told im an idiot than just stabbed in the back from behind

i think stackexchange should introduce anonymous comments to votes that you have to provide a publicly anonymous one liner to go with your vote

You didn't mention your Ubuntu version, so that may be someone's reason for a downvote(or it may be something completely different). I had the exact opposite problem (I needed more logs), but the solution is the same, so +1 and an answer from me.

You can limit the size of the logs. The Apache logs are rotated by logrotate. Edit /etc/logrotate.d/apache2 if you want to change the Apache logrotate configuration. If you want to control the maximum size, you can use size 100M or something similar.
size [size]

Log files are rotated only if they grow bigger than size
bytes.  If size is followed by k, the size is assumed to
be in kilobytes.  If M is used, the size is in megabytes,
and if G is used, the size is in gigabytes. So size 100,
size 100k, size 100M and size 100G are all valid.  This
option is mutually exclusive with the time interval
options, and it causes log files to be rotated without
regard for the last rotation time, if specified after the
time criteria (the last specified option takes the
precedence).

Testing
Test your configuration to make sure there are no syntax errors. The -d flag stands for debug mode, and it will show you what logrotate would do, but it won't actually rotate any logs:
sudo logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf

Force log rotation
The logrotate tool runs according to the schedule set in your system's cron jobs and it reads the configuration files every time it runs. This means any changes you make to the config files will be picked up the next time logrotate is executed. However, you can force a log rotation. The -f flag stands for force mode, which forces the rotation even if it doesn't seem necessary according to the logrotate configuration. To apply the changes immediately and rotate the logs manually, you can run:
sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf


thank you, i will try it and get back to you
